# What is the best Android phone for remote ssh administration/scripting?

Tags: ssh, shell, android, shell-scripting

I've got a Moto Droid that I use with connectbot for remote admin on Linux webservers.

However, I'm wondering if there are any Android phones out there with better hard keyboards for use with ConnectBot.

I basically want/need easy access to the various unixy characters like ~ | ` etc.

I write scripts in somewhat sigil heavy languages (Ruby, Perl, Shell) so the ability to easily generate those characters without having to go to the software keyboard would be nice.

Comment: Are you sure you want a phone for something this essential? I'd consider picking up 7 inch eeePC or 9 inch Dell Mini from eBay.

Comment: Agreed that a nettop might be your best bet, especially considering that instead of paying for a broadband account, you can leverage your droid and use wifi tethering to provide it with a network connection.

Answer (score 1):

I use Server Auditor as ssh client where most popular touch gestures are used, e.g. arrow keys - swipes, page up/down and home/end - two finger swipe, tab - double tap etc. Also it's very useful with Emacs or Screen because you are able to lock Ctrl or Alt buttons for several keys, e.g Ctr-x Ctr-s at Emacs. IMHO, for now it has the best UI as a ssh client.

Answer (score 0):

To get more characters on the keyboard, you tend to need a row of buttons for numbers, such as the [HTC Dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream) (aka the T-Mobile G1) had.

Looking at [this list of 2011 Android QWERTY sliders](http://www.androidauthority.com/the-best-qwerty-android-phones-in-2011-compared-10391/) the only one with a row of buttons is the Samsung Epic 4G.  It seems to have a ~ and a |, but no `.

[image: Samsung Epic 4G]

([Larger image](http://weblogs.dailypress.com/technology/pressforward/blog/SamsungEpic4Gopen.jpg))